# getting most recent result - mysql, left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 3 tables: 
 'art' contains a list of products ('art_id', 'art_nom' for name)
 'mag' is the list of shops ('mag_id')
 'pri' contains the prices of the products for a specific shop. There are several prices for one product, and even several prices for one shop, depending on the date ('pri_pri' is the price, 'pri_dat' is the date at which the price was registered and is on the datetime format).

I want the list of the products with 3 associated most recent prices (for the 3 shops selected). I got them with this request:

```
SELECT art.art_id, art_nom,  
    pri0.pri_pri AS pri_pri0, 
    pri1.pri_pri AS pri_pri1, 
    pri2.pri_pri AS pri_pri2 
FROM (((art 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pri_pri, art_id, mag_id AS nbr_pri0 FROM pri WHERE mag_id = '7081' GROUP BY art_id) AS pri0 ON art.art_id = pri0.art_id) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pri_pri, art_id, mag_id AS nbr_pri1 FROM pri WHERE mag_id = '14432' GROUP BY art_id) AS pri1 ON art.art_id = pri1.art_id) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pri_pri, art_id, mag_id AS nbr_pri2 FROM pri WHERE mag_id = '14515' GROUP BY art_id) AS pri2 ON art.art_id = pri2.art_id)
```

I receive the list as I want, except that I don't have the most recent price. 
So if somebody could help me adding a condition getting the most recent price, that would be really appreciated.

And I am really not sure if this way is very efficient. So if you have some advice on simplifying it...

Thanks !

note: i simplified my request so it is easier to read. If you want the complete request, with 5 prices and an 'ORDER BY' on the quantity of prices, here it is:

```
SELECT art.art_id, cat_id1, cat_id2, cat_id3, art_ean, art_nom, art_unt, art_qtt, 
    mrq_nom, mrq_img, 
    (IFNULL(nbr_pri0, 0) + IFNULL(nbr_pri1, 0) + IFNULL(nbr_pri2, 0) + IFNULL(nbr_pri3, 0) + IFNULL(nbr_pri4, 0)) AS nbr_pri, 
    nbr_pri0, pri0.pri_pri AS pri_pri0, 
    nbr_pri1, pri1.pri_pri AS pri_pri1, 
    nbr_pri2, pri2.pri_pri AS pri_pri2, 
    nbr_pri3, pri3.pri_pri AS pri_pri3, 
    nbr_pri4, pri4.pri_pri AS pri_pri4 
FROM mrq, (((((art 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pri_pri, art_id, mag_id, COUNT(pri_id) AS nbr_pri0 FROM pri WHERE mag_id = '7081' GROUP BY art_id) AS pri0 ON art.art_id = pri0.art_id) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pri_pri, art_id, mag_id, COUNT(pri_id) AS nbr_pri1 FROM pri WHERE mag_id = '14432' GROUP BY art_id) AS pri1 ON art.art_id = pri1.art_id) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pri_pri, art_id, mag_id, COUNT(pri_id) AS nbr_pri2 FROM pri WHERE mag_id = '14515' GROUP BY art_id) AS pri2 ON art.art_id = pri2.art_id) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pri_pri, art_id, mag_id, COUNT(pri_id) AS nbr_pri3 FROM pri WHERE mag_id = '12458' GROUP BY art_id) AS pri3 ON art.art_id = pri3.art_id) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pri_pri, art_id, mag_id, COUNT(pri_id) AS nbr_pri4 FROM pri WHERE mag_id = '8136' GROUP BY art_id) AS pri4 ON art.art_id = pri4.art_id) 
WHERE mrq.mrq_id = art.mrq_id 
ORDER BY nbr_pri DESC 
LIMIT 0,50
```

edit: here are the scripts for the tables as asked by Nitu and Strawberry (i hope so, i am not sure of what "DDLs" and "sqlfiddle" mean):

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `art` (
`art_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`art_nom` char(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`art_id`)
);
    INSERT INTO `art` (`art_id`, `art_nom`) VALUES
(1, 'Coca-Cola classic'),
(2, 'Coca-Cola vanille'),
(3, 'Coca-Cola Cherry'),
(4, 'Coca-Cola Light lemon');


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mag` (
`mag_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`mag_vil` char(100) NOT NULL,
`mag_nom` char(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`mag_id`)
);
    INSERT INTO `mag` (`mag_id`, `mag_vil`, `mag_nom`) VALUES
(2, '01100 Oyonnax', 'Petit Casino Oyonnax'),
(3, '75001 Paris', 'Petit Casino Paris'),
(4, '69001 Lyon', 'Petit Casino Lyon');


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pri` (
`pri_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`art_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`mag_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
`pri_pri` float NOT NULL,
`pri_dat` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`pri_id`)
);
    INSERT INTO `pri` (`pri_id`, `art_id`, `mag_id`, `pri_pri`, `pri_dat`) VALUES
(1, 1, 14515, 2.61, '2014-08-12 17:28:48'),
(2, 1, 12458, 1.74, '2014-04-01 17:52:00'),
(3, 1, 12458, 2.39, '2014-03-15 17:52:00'),
(4, 3, 12458, 1.93, '2014-07-31 20:00:00'),
(5, 3, 8136, 1.21, '2014-08-08 14:02:00');
```

edit of the edit: for this data, I want to receive the price 1.74 (pri_id = 2) for the product art_id = 1, because the date is more recent than for the price 2.39 (pri_id = 3)

Comment: it would be better if you provide the scripts for these table.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so (you haven't), provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your subqueries to something like

```
SELECT pri_date, MAX(pri_date) AS maxdate, pri_pri, art_id, mag_id, COUNT(pri_id) AS nbr_pri0 
    FROM pri 
    WHERE mag_id = '7081' 
    GROUP BY art_id 
    HAVING maxdate=pri_date
```

Which will give you the recent date.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Argeman. But with this subquery, I don't get the products which have several prices. I only get the products with only 1 price. Any idea why ?

Comment: I made a subquery in the subquery. Which gave me this: 
 SELECT pri_pri, art_id, mag_id, COUNT(pri_id) AS nbr_pri 
 FROM pri AS pri_in 
 WHERE mag_id = '1234' 
 AND pri_dat = (
  SELECT MAX(pri_dat) 
  FROM pri 
  WHERE art_id = pri_in.art_id 
  AND mag_id = '1234'
 ) GROUP BY art_id